# JavaScript - How to define Properties in Object Definition

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, getter

How can I define a property inside an object definition, so I can use it inside the constructor?

For Example:
When I define an object Window inside my namespace WindowManager with the properties 'x' and 'y', I want to use WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_X and WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_Y to handle undefined / null arguments in my constructor. Like this:

```
var WindowManager = {
   Window: {
      get DEFAULT_X () {
         return 0;
      },
      get DEFAULT_Y () {
         return 0;
      },

      constructor: function Window (xPos, yPos) {
         this.x = xPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_X;
         this.y = yPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_Y;
      },

      prototype: {
         x: undefined,
         y: undefined
      }
   }
};
WindowManager.Window = WindowManager.Window.constructor;
```

How will I have to change my code, so I can use these 'static' properties inside the constructor and maintaining some somewhat elegant code?

I don't want my code to look something like this:

```
WindowManager.Window.__defineGetter__ ("DEFAULT_X", function getDEFAULT_X () {
   return 0;
});
// ...
WindowManager.Window.constructor = function Window (xPos, yPos) {
   this.x = xPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_X;
   this.y = yPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_Y;
};
```

Comment: Will `DEFAULT_X`/`Y` ever change? I don't fully understand why it's important to make them getter-based if all the getter ever does is return 0.

Comment: `this.x = xPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_X;` if `xPos` is `0` then `this.x` will take the default value, it is usually best to manually test for `undefined` and `null`: `if (typeof foo === "undefined" || foo === null)`. Oh the funs of javascript...

Comment: DEFAULT_X and DEFAULT_Y are defined as getters, so they behave like constants. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I used the || operator like this to shorten the example code. I'm aware of javascript's 'beauty'.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably using a closure

```
var Window;

(function() {
   var DEFAULT_X= 100;
   var DEFAULT_Y= 100;
   Window= function (x, y) {
      if (typeof x === "undefined" || x === null)
         this.x= DEFAULT_X;
      else
         this.x = x;

      if (typeof y === "undefined" || y === null)
         this.y= DEFAULT_Y;
      else
         this.y = y;
   }
}());

WindowManager= {
   window: new Window(10, 20)
};
```

This pattern is called [Immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and it is used to hide variables from the outside scope. This way DEFAULT_X and DEFAULT_Y are only visible in the Window constructor.

Also `this.x = xPos || WindowManager.Window.DEFAULT_X;` if `xPos` is `0` then `this.x` will take the default value, it is usually best to manually test for `undefined` and `null`: `if (typeof foo === "undefined" || foo === null)`.

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript (not counting ECMAScript 6), the constructor *is* the object definition**. To use something equivalent to static properties, you would attach these to the function itself, rather than to the function's `prototype` property. In your case, it might look something like this:

```
var WindowManager = {};
// Define the Window object.
// NOTE: This function has a bug, because if DEFAULT_X and DEFAULT_Y
// are not zero, then it will be impossible to set a window to (0,0).
// I have kept the code as-is, to show how it corresponds to the example
// you provided.

function Window(xPos, yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos || Window.DEFAULT_X;
    this.yPos = yPos || Window.DEFAULT_Y;
}

// Static properties of Window.
Window.DEFAULT_X = 0;
Window.DEFAULT_Y = 0;

WindowManager.Window = Window;
```

**ECMAScript 6 will change this somewhat, by introducing a syntax for class definitions**. But that syntax, as currently defined, is basically sugar for what I've done above. ECMAScript 6 still defines a constructor function like this one, non-static members go to that function's `prototype` property, static members still become properties of that function, and so on.